# Sample JSON for View/Edit MultiStep Form with All Types of Control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I need json examples of multi step forms which has different types of controls like radio button, check box, dropdown,calendar. I need json for both view & edit form? Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I searched online for "JSON form builder" and was able to find some pretty awesome frameworks and examples. I am not going to include them here because the authors do a far better job explaining the examples.

#### My current favorite

https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform/wiki#outline

#### Try it out in the play ground.

http://ulion.github.io/jsonform/playground/

### Shortcomings

I am not sure if it meets all your requirements. However, it could be extended with other technologies.

#### Calender

HTML5 `<input type="date">`

#### Multi step forms

jQuery and CSS
http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar